# When should I use memcpy and when should I use memmove?

Tags: memcpy, memmove

Is there any important difference between the memcpy and the memmove functions?
When should I use memcpy and when should I use memmove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `memmove` when there's a chance that the source and destination buffers overlap - it is specified to work in that case, whereas `memcpy` isn't.

In theory `memcpy` can be faster, if only because it doesn't check for overlapping memory buffers.